# Errors with dictionary in pymysql

Tags: python, mysql, dictionary, pymysql

I get the following error:

```
if 'ShazK01' in LogRef.values():
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'
```

After running:

```
import pymysql 

db = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', ..)
cur = db.cursor() 

def getData():
     LoginInput=[]
     InputUN = ('ShazK01') 
     InputPC = ('passinput') 
     LoginInput=[InputUN, InputPC] 
     return LoginInput


def checkExistence():
     cur = db.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
     cur.execute("SELECT Username FROM LoginDetails") 
     LogRef = cur.fetchall() #fetch ALL login references
     print(LogRef)
     if 'ShazK01' in LogRef.values():
          print("yes")
     else:
          print("no")

LoginInput = getData()
print(LoginInput)            
print(LoginInput[0])
UNInput = LoginInput[0]
print(UNInput)
checkExistence()
```

I've looked at other answers and they haven't been helpful. So, any helpful advice is appreciated as I'm a beginner with using sql and python together, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyMysql's `fetchall` returns a list (a list of dictionaries here - because of `pymysql.cursors.DictCursor`). You'll have to write something like

```
from itertools import chain
it = chain.from_iterable(x.values() for x in cur.fetchall())
print('yes' if 'ShazK01' in it else 'no')
```

or

```
print('yes' if any('ShazK01' in x.values() for x in cur.fetchall()) else 'no')
```

Comment: How can I use this to search for another attribute in the same row? What if I wanted to obtain the value for "SELECT Passcode FROM LoginDetails WHERE Username= 'ShazK01'"

Comment: @AnbarHussain I don't understand... If you want to get just one row, you'd use `fetchone`. If you want to get the matched `dict` object, you could use `next(x for x in cur.fetchall() if x['Username'] == 'ShazK01')` or something like that.